# Programmatically Get Page Layout being used by a SharePoint Page

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Wondered if it's possible to iterate through the pages held in the pages library and determine the page layout being used by each page? any c# code examples appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to a [PublishingWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb.aspx) object and throught that the PublishingPage object which has a [Layout property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingpage.layout.aspx).

Below I have butchered the two pages example code to get something close to what you need.

```
 using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(webUri.AbsolutePath)))
            {
                PublishingWeb pWeb = null;

                if (!web.Exists || !PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(web))
                {
                  return;
                }

                pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
                PublishingPageCollection publishingPages = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages();
                foreach (PublishingPage publishingPage in publishingPages)
                {
                   //do something here with publishingPage.Layout
                }               
            }
```